# Why i cant reach instance of object in object array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, instance-variables

I'm starting to learn java, and faced this problem when I can reach object name and lastName, but can't reach if I put them in object array.

```
public class Human {
    String name;
    String lastName;
    String[] people;

    People(String name, String lastName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    };

    public static People tom = new People("Tom", "Tommy");
    public static People ted = new People("Ted", "Teddy");

    public static Object[] objects = {
            tom,
            ted
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(tom.lastName);
        System.out.println(objects[0]);
```

and this line I need does not work.

```
        System.out.println(objects[0].lastName); 
}
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: You should declare `objects` as `People[]`

Comment: cannot resolve symbol, but it makes no sense

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Comment: It's not *directly* to your question; but `this.name = lastName;` ***should*** be `this.lastName = lastName;` - that kind of bug can be difficult to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: you declared that array of type *Object*.

Objects don't have names, only an instance of People has!

In other words: you want to declare an array of People, not Object.

You see, the compiler only "remembers" the type that is used on the left hand side of that variable declaration. It does not know that you in fact created an array of Object and placed solely instances of People inside that array.

And unrelated: people implies plural. You should rather call that class Person, or maybe PersonInfo.

Answer (score 3):

Here, `Object[] objects` is an array of `Object` and Object class does not have anything like `lastName`. There is two way to solve the problem.

1. Declare the array as `People[] objects`
   or
2. Cast the object to people like `((People)objects[0]).lastName`